# How can i resize uploaded image to some specific height and width using express fileupload

Tags: node.js, express-fileupload

hi I'm using express file upload for uploading images in my NodeJS project but I need to resize the uploading image to 1000*1000 size and save to folder how can i do that

```
router.post('/add-product', (req, res) => {
// console.log(req.body)
let product=req.body
product.price=parseInt(product.price)
console.log(req.files.image);

let imgCount = req.body.len
producthelper.addProduct(req.body,(id)=>{
    let image=req.files.image

    if(imgCount == 1)
    {
        image.mv('./public/images/product-images/'+id+'-'+0+'.jpg',(err,done)=>{
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }
    else{
        for(let i=0;i<imgCount;i++)
        {
            image[i].mv('./public/images/product-images/'+id+'-'+i+'.jpg',(err,done)=>{
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            }) 
        }
    }
    req.flash('success_msg',"Successfully Added Your Product for Sell...")
    res.redirect('/sellproduct')
})
```

})

this is my code to save the image in the folder how to replace the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sharp` npm package for that. For example.

```
sharp(inputBuffer)
   .resize(1000, 1000)
   .toFile('outputimage.jpeg', (err, info) => { ... });
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

Comment: Thanks for ur reply could u pls clear ur ans with this code that i just added